# A problem when change view of NavigationController in InterfaceBuilder?

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, uinavigationcontroller

default it link to RootViewController when i want to change it to another view it got some crash
did it have a solution (InterfaceBuilder) for change view to another class   ?

when run program got some error

```
[Session started at 2010-01-20 10:17:14 +0700.]
2010-01-20 10:17:16.560 AsianDelight[2816:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "TestFC" nib but the view outlet was not set.'
2010-01-20 10:17:16.577 AsianDelight[2816:207] Stack: (
    30409819,
    2481497353,
    30493755,
    30493594,
    3293754,
    3287099,
    3286817,
    3280274,
    3322548,
    3318574,
    3325210,
    3306266,
    4477668,
    29000368,
    28999791,
    29081215,
    3283858,
    2890716,
    2869039,
    2863409,
    3279229,
    3321733,
    2940469,
    2933949,
    2933720,
    2907787,
    8022,
    2770463,
    2808330,
    2796424,
    2778835,
    2805941,
    38506193,
    30194560,
    30190664,
    2772585
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your TestFC.xib file did not have its view outlet set to the File's Owner.